# This keyword with scala and anonymous functions/classes

Tags: java, scala

In Java, I could reference the outer instance of a particular class:
Sorry, I meant this.

```
object obj extends SomeOtherClass {
def myMethodOfSomeInstance = {
val uiThread = new SomeClass {
          def run: Unit = {
            chooser.showOpenDialog(SomeOtherClass.this)            
          }
        }
}
```

...
This code does not compile, but on this line, I want to reference the parent instance?  How do I do that?

chooser.showOpenDialog(SomeOtherClass.this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a self reference in the enclosing object that you can refer to:

```
object SomeObject { outer =>
  def myMethodOfSomeInstance = {
    val uiThread = new SomeClass {
      def run: Unit = {
        chooser.showOpenDialog(outer)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** By the way your declaration of the object would have to be `object obj extends SomeOtherClass` for being valid scala code. You could then also refer to the enclosing object with `obj.this`.

Comment: The `outer` is called a *self type annotation*.